# Linq to SQL Join Allowing Nulls When I don't want that

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've written the below query to join a couple of tables. The la.UserProfileId is nullable for some ungodly reason.

When I write the equivalent SQL statement, I get 0 records as I should at this point.

```
var result = (from e in _ctx.Employees
                     join la in _ctx.LoginAudits on e.UserProfile.Id equals la.UserProfileId.Value
                     where la.LoginDate >= fromDate
                     && e.Client.Id == clientID
                     select new
                     {
                         la.Id,
                         employeeID = e.Id,
                         e.Client.DisplayName,
                         la.UserProfileId
                     }).ToList();
```

The above LINQ code generates the below SQL.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Extent3].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
[Extent2].[UserProfileId] AS [UserProfileId]
FROM   [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[LoginAudits] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[UserProfile_Id] = [Extent2].[UserProfileId]) OR (([Extent1].[UserProfile_Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[UserProfileId] IS NULL))
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Client_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
WHERE ([Extent2].[LoginDate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Client_Id] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 bigint',@p__linq__0='2018-02-09 11:11:29.1047249',@p__linq__1=37
```

As you can see, it includes "OR (([Extent1].[UserProfile_Id] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[UserProfileId] IS NULL))"

That is the exact opposite of what I want. How do I make it do a normal inner join and not try to allow for null values?

I was able to work around this by adding && la.UserProfileId != null in my WHERE clause, but ideally I'd rather make the JOIN behave like normal INNER JOIN and not try to anticipate stuff I don't ask for.

Comment: Are the fields NULLable in the model? If so, try e.UserProfile.Id.Value instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That is the exact opposite of what I want. How do I make it do a normal inner join and not try to allow for null values?

The reasoning behind is that in C# `null == null` evaluates to `true`, while in SQL it evaluates to `NULL` (and basically is handled like `FALSE`). So EF is trying to emulate the C# behavior in order to get the same result as if you were running the same query in LINQ to Objects.

This is the default EF6 behavior. It is controlled by the [`UseDatabaseNullSemantics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics)) property, so if you want to use the SQL behavior, you should set it to `true` in your `DbContext` derived class constructor or from outside:

```
[dbContext.]Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

But that's not enough though. It affects all the comparison operators, but they forgot to apply it to joins. The solution is to not use LINQ `join` operator, but correlated `where` (EF is smart enough to turn it into SQL `JOIN`).

So additionally to setting `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to `true`, replace

```
join la in _ctx.LoginAudits on e.UserProfile.Id equals la.UserProfileId
```

with

```
from la in _ctx.LoginAudits where e.UserProfile.Id == la.UserProfileId
```

and you'll get the desired `INNER JOIN`.